# How to add multiple title to Python Plot using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have a code which plots images and I use subplots to show multiple images on the plot. I need to print the varible values (var1, var2 and var3) on top of the image along with the image title.

The code is something like this:

```
plt.subplot(2,3,1);
plt.imshow(img[], cmap = 'grey'); 
plt.title('Image1'); 
plt.title(var1)            # here we print the value stored in the var1 on top of the image next to title
plt.title(var2)           # var2 is also printed on top of the image 
plt.title(var3)
```

var1, var2, var3 are float values.

I tried using:

```
plt.title(var1, loc=('left'))
```

But this somehow overlaps over the image title.

The variable values needs to be printed above the image ( and the title - 'Image1' should also be present.

What is the best way to do this?

P.S. Matplotlib is to be used. Have a look at example image for reference.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkqGV.png)

Comment: use an f-string with `\n`, something like: `plt.title(f'var1={var1}\nvar2={var2}\nvar3={var3}\nBird_image')`

Comment: or rounded to 3 decimals: `plt.title(f'var1={var1:.3f}\nvar2={var2:.3f}\nvar3={var3:.3f}\nBird_image')`